# Executing command with runtime().exec

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I try to check if a service is installed on Windows using:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
   "sc query type= service state= all | find\"postgresql\"");
```

but the output is exactly as if I had executed the `sc` command by itself (a help message). When executing the same string via `cmd` it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
String[] cmd = new String[4]; 
cmd[0] = "sc"; 
cmd[1] = "query"; 
cmd[2] ="type=service"; 
cmd[3] = "state= all | find\"postgresql\"";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and tried the solution using an array, but it did not work for me.

So I used the command below. In my case I had to search the service in the return, because I had not the exact service name. In your case, you can put the process name or server name in the WHERE clause:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic SERVICE WHERE State=\"Running\" get Name,PathName /format:LIST");
```

Important: The wmic is present just in Windows XP Professional or higher!